# Calling multiple user controls in parallel - asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page that calls multiple user controls (almost 15 user controls) synchronously. Recently when we ran the webpagetest, our page speed was very bad and now we are looking to optimize the page to improve page speed. So my question is how can i call multiple user controls in the page asynchronously? we are using asp.net web forms . does using aysnc and await will help us calling user controls in parallel without waiting for other user controls ?

Comment: Can you clarify what this means: "calls multiple user controls."

Comment: <item:OverallRating ID ="OverallRating1" runat ="server"  visible='false'/>
<item:ItemImage ID="ItemImage1" runat="server" />
<item:RecommendAccessoriesFeatured ID="RecommendAccessoriesFeatured1" runat="server" />  we are using multiple user controls in the web page and each user controls has unique functionality. One user controls get product rating, other gets Images and so on.

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean by *calling* them?

Comment: Try this. It might help. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx. This is referring to the page itself, but it should apply to events with user controls as well.

Comment: In ASP.NET web forms, all those controls are designed to emit HTML into the HTTP response stream. The stream is a one-dimensional, one-directional array of UTF8 characters, and as such it has to be constructed *in series*, one after the other. Rendering those controls asynchronously would be a huge problem, and could actually make performance worse since you'd have to buffer the output. That being said, I'm willing to bet $1 that your problem is *not* the number of controls. Maybe look at the way you are retrieving the data to populate them.

Comment: @JohnWu ..Thanks for your comment. I am planning to rewrite the page into a single page application using Angular where i can use multiple async calls instead of dealing with the old asp.net crap.

Comment: That's a much more modern tech and a good choice. Web forms is 13 years old and yes it doesn't really deliver for Web 2.0 feature functionality.